# How can i query for the type in opportunity stage?

Tags: apex, opportunity

How do i query for all opportunities which has the type "Closed/won" on opportunityStage not the stage "Closed/Won". We have a few stages which are of Type Closed/Won but not with the stagename as closed/won

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `IsWon` field in your SOQL condition expression.  For example,

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE IsWon = TRUE
```

will return all Opportunities with any StageName of Type `Closed/Won`.

Comment: If someone is looking for the opposite, it's the `IsClosed` field.